# String Injection in Twitter's inputfield with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, twitter, html-injections

I am trying to build a Chrome extension that generates texts on Twitter. I am struggling with injecting the text in the inputfield.

Here is how I do it:

- If the user has already input some content, it works great
- If the user has not already input content, I have to slightly change the HTML (remove the default `<br>` and add a `<span>`)

However, on the second use case, it just doesn't work. The placeholder stays visible and the inputfied is broken.

See it in action:
=> https://www.loom.com/share/4bac993ba2cd4ee4a38fc209e751e323

(images if you don't want to check the video)
[image]

[image]

Am I missing something?
Is there some kind of JS variable on change in addition to changes in the HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Try document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101620).

Comment: Thanks it almost works! 
Perfectly works if you have already input something in the Twitter's tweet area. 
If not, it breaks it. 
It's like the textarea is not "activated"